# Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Expected hex 0x in '{0xdddddddd, etc}'

Tags: sharepoint

I am getting below error message at the time visual studio activate the feature during deployment

Error Message "Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Expected hex 0x in '{0xdddddddd, etc}'"

Please find the step details which i have used to create solution/project:

## 1 Create a Empty sharepoint project in visual studio  and set the version 3.5 and target frame work 64X.

## 2 Add new feature and then event receiver and not done any customization.

## 3 Deeply the solution and getting above error at the time of feature activate.

Note : i have tried to deploy on both sandbox or farm but no difference.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure any **GUIDs** used in your solution except Features has a dash mark '-'
like this **{02C414A0-DC73-46F2-A219-0B4A5D1E3AAE}**.